# How to draw a horizontal edge between cousins in a forest tree (without using explicit tiers)

Tags: forest

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line between two nodes in a `forest` tree that have an equal distance to the root node (hence being siblings or cousins of nth degree).

Using the relative node names given in §3.5 of the `forest` manual, it's actually quite easy to achieve this for siblings. This is how far I got:

```
\documentclass[
  ,crop=true
  ,varwidth=\maxdimen
  ]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  <--/.style={ % draw horizontal line to predecessor
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[dashed](!)--(!p);}}},
  -->/.style={ % draw horizontal line to successor
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[dashed](!)--(!n);}}},
  -->>/.style={ % draw horizontal line to successor cousin
    before drawing tree={tikz+={\draw[dashed](!)--(!>);}}},
}

\begin{document}

\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,--> [NP,-->>,tier=cousin1th [D [the]]]]
    [S,--> [NP,-->>,tier=cousin1th [A [absent]]]]
    [S, [NP,tier=cousin1th [N [student]]]]
    ]
} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

I defined options `<--` and `-->` in order draw horizontal edges to the previous or next sibling. However, when trying to extend this to adjacent cousins of nth degree (see `-->>`), I have to expicitely specify the `tier` in the respective nodes. Is there a way to achieve this without using `tier`? For example, in the MWE, I'd like to connect the two NP nodes in a similar way, i.e. without `tier=cousin1th`.

Comment: I would avoid `<` and, especially, `>`. Forest already uses them so extensively this will be, at best, confusing to humans. Also, the notion of a cousin does not seem well-defined unless it is intended to apply only to trees meeting unspecified structural restrictions. To put this another way, what counts as 'equally distant' from the root exactly? The tier thing isn't part of your question - I don't know whether that matters or not or whether you changed your mind after writing the title, and I don't know whether it is supposed to be a clue or not, either.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your remarks. I've changes the option names and also clarified what I meant by referring to tiers in the title. "equally distant" means that the dominance path from the root is equal in length.

Comment: @cfr I also removed `no edge` in the options as it was either ineffective (siblings) or causing the tree to look odd (cousins).

Comment: What's the 'dominance path'? I'm not a linguist.

Comment: You might look at the way `c-commanded` is defined, too. That's not what you want here, but the way it is implemented might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems an odd thing to want to do ... which makes me wonder whether it is really what you want to do here.

The notion of a 'cousin' does not seem well-defined unless it is intended to apply only to trees meeting unspecified structural restrictions.

What happens when ancestors have different numbers of children, for example? Is the cousin the closer one horizontally or vertically?

To put this another way, what counts as 'equally distant' from the root exactly? Is the 11th child of the 4th child of the 3rd child of the root an equal distance from the 7th child of the 2nd child of the 2nd child of the 4th child of the root? Does it matter whether it is the 11th child of 22 or the 11th child of 11? Or is it just steps to root? So all nodes on a level are cousins?

Be that as it may, the following implements *a* notion of 'cousinhood'. This notion is consistent with the examples in the question, but whether it coincides with any notion intended or useful is rather more questionable.

```
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,  [NP,  [D,  [the, ]]]]
    [S, twp  [NP, twp [N, twp [student, twp]]]]
  ]
}
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S, twn [NP, twn [D, twn [the, twn]]]]
    [S,   [NP,  [N,  [student, ]]]]
  ]
}
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S, twn [NP, twn [D,  [the, twn]]]]
    [S, twp  [NP,  [N, twp [student, ]]]]
  ]
}
```

[image: cousins in some sense of 'cousin']

Note that the code is designed to just fail silently if you request a relationship be shown between a node and a non-existent 'cousin'.

Also, something like

```
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,  [NP,  [D,  [the, twn ]]]]
    [S,  [A,  [absent, twn ]]]
    [S, twp  [NP, twp [N, twp [student]]]]
  ]
}
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,  [A,  [absent, ]]]
    [S,  [NP,  [D,  [the, ]]]]
    [S, twp  [NP, twp [N, twp [student, twp]]]]
  ]
}
```

will produce something like the following

[image: linguistic mash?]

which may not be what's expected. (But then, what is?)

Obviously the above is linguistic nonsense. At least, it would be astonishing if it happened not to be. Nonetheless, the code will compile. Whether that is an advantage is a different matter.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  conn/.style n args=2{
    no edge,
    tikz+={\draw [dashed] (#1) -- (#2);}
  },
  twn/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      temptoksa=,
      tempcounta/.option=level,
      if nodewalk valid={n}{conn={}{!n}}{
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={u}{
            tempcountb/.option=n,
            u,
            if={> OR>{n children}{tempcountb} }{
              tempcountc/.register=tempcountb,
              tempcountc'+=1,
              n/.register=tempcountc,
              while nodewalk valid={1}{
                1,
                if={ > OR= {level}{tempcounta} }{
                  temptoksa/.option=name,
                  break=1
                }{}
              }
            }{}
          }
        }{},
        if temptoksa={}{}{conn/.process={_R {}{temptoksa}}}
      },
    },
  },
  twp/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      temptoksa=,
      tempcounta/.option=level,
      if nodewalk valid={p}{conn={}{!p}}{
        for nodewalk={
          while nodewalk valid={u}{
            u,
            if n=1{}{
              p,
              while nodewalk valid={1}{
                1,
                if={ > OR= {level}{tempcounta} }{
                  temptoksa/.option=name,
                  break=1
                }{}
              }
            },
          }
        }{},
        if temptoksa={}{}{conn/.process={_R {}{temptoksa}}}
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}

\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S,  [NP,  [D,  [the, ]]]]
    [S, twp  [NP, twp [N, twp [student, twp]]]]
  ]
}
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S, twn [NP, twn [D, twn [the, twn]]]]
    [S,   [NP,  [N,  [student, ]]]]
  ]
}
\Forest{
  [,phantom
    [S, twn [NP, twn [D,  [the, twn]]]]
    [S, twp  [NP,  [N, twp [student, ]]]]
  ]
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove `no edge` in the `conn` options and the trees make a lot more sense linguistically. Of course, you can still draw something that looks dubious ... (e.g. the edge between _the_ and _student_). Again, I'd like to be able to connect adjacent cousins of nth degree which I take to be linearly adjacent nodes which have an equal vertical distance (in terms of the length of the dominance path) to the root node. The last part is probaby what you mean by "all nodes on a level are cousins". Anyway, your code is doing what I was looking for, so thanks!

Comment: @Timm Trouble is, I'm not a linguist, so I can't tell ;). I just took the `no edge` from the styles you originally posted. (That is, I'm buck passing back to you :).)

Comment: There's something wrong in the definition of `twp`: instead of `while nodewalk valid={1}{1,`, it should read `while nodewalk valid={last}{last,`. With the first variant, the edge will connect with the **leftmost** cousin. But it should connect with the one closest to the left.

Comment: @Timm Perhaps. The problem is I was guessing which concept I was trying to implement - as I indicated in the post.

Comment: @Timm Try maybe `l` in place of `1`?

Comment: Does `l` have the same meaning as `last`? Don't get me wrong: Your code helps a lot, even though I had to fix one detail to get it working in the way I wanted it to work ;-) That is, I always want to connect adjacent cousins.

Comment: @Timm Yes, it should. It is the first child in the other direction (I guess `l` is the shortened form of `last`, I expect.)